# How to copy a file to mapped network drive with python

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to copy files from a folder in my C drive to a mapped network Drive (Z) and am receiving an error using shutil.copy, can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks!  Here's the code below, much of which is borrowed from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876204/python-script-to-move-specific-files-from-one-folder-to-another?newreg=832b2909913b4e5a96c952359cec0ad5)

```
import os, shutil, re
from os import path

start_file = "C:\\data\\"
end_file = "Z:\\test\\"

files = os.listdir(start_file)

file_list = [i for i in os.listdir(start_file) if and path.isfile(path.join(start_file, i))]


for f in file_list:
    shutil.copy(path.join(start_file, f), end_file)
```

The exact error I'm getting is "Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory" on the last line of that code block

Comment: Do you have your `end_file` created in your Z drive?

Comment: That can't be your exact code; `file_list = ... if and path.isfile...` is a syntax error.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `xcopy` or `robocopy` to do this task?  There's no advantage to using Python here.